# Check the dropdowns and change cell colors dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, drop-down-menu

I have a web table displaying a sql server database table using php pdo. The table is created and displayed on index.php file. I have a form in edit.php where users can update the table. Some of the fields in edit.php have dropdowns. For example, one field has dropdown options Q1,Q2,Q3,and Q4. If the initial value is Q1 or the user updates to Q1, I want to make the background color of the cell in table to be green, if Q2=>yellow, Q3=>red. Can somebody please help me with this? I have index.php and edit.php shown below:

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('include/database.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>     </head>
<body>
<tr><th>Q Rating</th></tr>
<tr><th>Action</th></tr>

<?php
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MATRIX ORDER BY OBJECTID ASC");
        $stmt ->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {

        ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?=$row['Q_Rating'];?></td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?=$row['OBJECTID'];?>">Edit </a>  </td>
```

Edit.php

```
   <form action="" method="post"> 
    <tr>
                <td>ATFP</td>
                <td><label>
                        <select name="txt_qrating" class="textfields"           id="q_rating">
                            <option id="0">Select One</option>
                            <option id="1"> Q1</option>
                            <option id="2">Q2</option>
                            <option id="3">Q3</option>
                            <option id="4">Q4</option>

                        </select>
                     </label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="txt_id" value="<?= $object_id; ?>">
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td><label><input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit">
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add some css style with proper classes:

```
.green { color: green;} .red { color: red;}
```

.. then add some inline conditionals like:

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td class="<?php echo ("quatity1" === $myvar ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>">tdValueHere</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thanks @drLeo. Can you please elaborate the third line of your inline conditionals. I am getting green and yellow color. If I can figure out how to organize the conditionals, your code is working fine.

Comment: It is just a ternary if operator:

Comment: return (0 === $var ? true : false) is the short case of: if(0===$var) { return true; } else { return false;}

Comment: I have four different options. Can I still use the ternary operator?

Comment: Normally yes, but you should group condition with parentheses like: 0 === $myVar ? 'red' : (1 === $myVar ? 'green' : (2 === $myVar ? 'yellow' : (3 === $myVar ? 'pink' : "") ....

Comment: If you have problems in writing a complex conditions use php conditional tags like: <tr><?php if("quantity 1 === $myVar) ?> <td class = "red"> <?php elseif("quantity2 === $myVar);?> <td class="green"> ... <?php endif;?>. Sorry for my lacunar answers but I'm mobile and is not very terrific ti write code with :) but I'm very confident that you already figured what I want to say ....

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much. I used if statements. My html and php are mixed, and they were confusing me a lot.